# mysql cannot find the right select query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build select for this table but I am getting strange results.
My tables:

```
tbl_main
–––––––––––––––––-
id  user_id     name

tbl_friends
–––––––––––––––––-
id  user_id     main_id people

tbl_cats
–––––––––––––––––-
id  user_id     main_id
```

Now I know user_id only. I would like to get results (array) with these items:

- I need list of id from tbl_main (results should be sorted by this tbl_main.id DESC)
- count how many unique people is in tbl_friends  when  tbl_friends.user_id=user_id AND tbl_friends.main_id=tbl_main.id
- get comma separated list (or array) of people values from tbl_friends when  tbl_friends.user_id=user_id AND tbl_friends.main_id=tbl_main.id
- count unique values of tbl_cats.user_id when tbl_cats.main_id = tbl_main.id

This should be result of one query. I am trying many  COUNT(DISTINCT) combinations but it is not working and I am completely lost. please help. many thanks

I tried something like this (see below). Results seem to be ok but is it the right way  how to do it (3 selects in one query)? And what about server load? Will it work ok with large data?

```
SELECT e.id
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ef.people) FROM tbl_friends ef WHERE ef.user_id=$user_id AND ef.main_id=e.id) as result_people, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT et.user_id) FROM tbl_cats et WHERE et.main_id=e.id) as total

FROM tbl_main e
WHERE e.user_id = $user_id
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

Comment: I tried something like:SELECT e.id, ef.people, COUNT(DISTINCT ef.people) AS countpeople, COUNT(DISTINCT ef.people) + COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_id) AS total, COUNT(DISTINCT et.user_id) AS total_times
FROM tbl_main e
JOIN tbl_friends ef ON (ef.main_id = e.id)
JOIN tbl_cats et ON (et.main_id = e.id)
WHERE e.user_id = $user_id
ORDER BY e.id DESC  but it is not good as I see.

Comment: @peter, don't add additional content to your own question in comments. Edit your original question instead and add the information there where it's easy to find and you can properly format it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to do but this should return the same result as your current query and be more efficient than the two scalar correlated sub queries -

```
SELECT
    tm.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tf.people) AS result_people,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tc.user_id) AS total
FROM tbl_main tm
LEFT JOIN tbl_friends tf
    ON tm.id = tf.main_id
    AND tm.user_id = tf.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_cats tc
    ON tm.id = tc.main_id
WHERE tm.user_id = $user_id
GROUP BY tm.id DESC
```

Compare the EXPLAIN output for the two queries and see how they fare.